# Pandas: How to return multiple columns with a custom apply function on a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

The basic idea is that I have a computation that involves multiple columns from a dataframe and returns multiple columns, which I'd like to integrate in the dataframe.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['i1', 'i1', 'i2', 'i2'], 'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,6,7,8]})

def custom_f(a, b):
    computation = a+b
    return computation + 1, computation*2

df['c1'], df['c2'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: custom_f(x.a, x.b))
```

Desired output:

```
    id  a   b  c1     c2
0   i1  1   5  7      12
1   i1  2   6  9      16
2   i2  3   7  11     20
3   i2  4   8  13     24
```

I know how I could do this one column at a time, but in reality the 'computation' operation using the two columns is quite expensive so I'm trying to figure out how I could only run it once.

EDIT: I realised that the given example can be solved without the groupby, but for my use case for the actual 'computation' I'm doing the groupby because I'm using the first and last values of arrays in each group for my computation. For the sake of simplicity I omitted that, but imagine that it is needed.

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['c1'], df['c2'] = custom_f(df['a'], df['b']) # you dont need apply for your desired output here
```

Comment: Thanks, I see thought that my example might have been too simple. In my real use case I do the groupby because I need to know the start/end points of each array of the grouped data frames for my computation.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
def custom_f(a, b):
    computation = a+b
    return pd.concat([(computation + 1),(computation*2)],axis=1)
```

Finally:

```
df[['c1','c2']]=df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: custom_f(x.a, x.b)).values
```

output of `df`:

```
    id  a   b   c1  c2
0   i1  1   5   7   12
1   i1  2   6   9   16
2   i2  3   7   11  20
3   i2  4   8   13  24
```